# PHP PDO Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined - why?

Tags: php, pdo, parameters

I'm getting the error when trying to submit the following sql code:

```
    $Query = "Insert into EzyCat15.CompanyCards (`CC_StoreID`, `EC_CC_Card_ID`, `CC_Card_Type`, `CC_Type`,
      `CC_Company_Name`, `CC_Company_Trading_Name`, `CC_ABN_Number`, 
        `CC_Tax_Code`, `CC_Shipping_Tax_Code`, `CC_Default_Currency`,
         `CC_Default_PriceType`,`CC_Payment_DueType`, `CC_ MethodInvoice`, `CC_InvoiceTemplate`, `CC_PrintPackingSlip`, `CC_PackingSlip_Template`, 
          `CC_Card_Status`, `CC_Fax`,
             `CC_URL`,
              `CC_ReviewedModifiedBy`)
               values 
               (:CC_StoreID, :EC_CC_Card_ID, :CC_Card_Type, :CC_Type,
                :CC_Company_Name, :CC_Company_Trading_Name, :CC_ABN_Number,
                  :CC_Tax_Code, :CC_Shipping_Tax_Code, :CC_Default_Currency, 
                 :CC_Default_PriceType,  :CC_Payment_DueType,:CC_ MethodInvoice, :CC_InvoiceTemplate, :CC_PrintPackingSlip, :CC_PackingSlip_Template,
                    :CC_Card_Status, :CC_Fax,
                      :CC_URL, 
                       :CC_ReviewedModifiedBy)";
    $this->CrosscheckPDO($Query, $data);
    $Query = $this -> conn -> prepare($Query);
    $Query -> execute($data);
```

I wrote a bit of code to strip the Parameters from the sql and compare it to my $data variable looking for missing data fields on both sides.

```
public function CrosscheckPDO($query, $params) {
    $r = explode(':', $query);
    unset($r[0]);

    foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
        $value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
        $value = trim(str_replace(')', '', $value));
        $r[$key] = $value;
        if (!isset($params[$value]))
            $params[$value] = '!!!!!';
        $t[$value] = $params[$value];
        unset($params[$value]);
    }
    echo "Query Variables";
    print_r($r);
    echo "Query Pairs";
    print_r($t);
    echo "Param Variables";
    print_r($params);
}
```

My output from CrossCheckPDO shows:

```
Query VariablesArray
(
    [1] => CC_StoreID
    [2] => EC_CC_Card_ID
    [3] => CC_Card_Type
    [4] => CC_Type
    [5] => CC_Company_Name
    [6] => CC_Company_Trading_Name
    [7] => CC_ABN_Number
    [8] => CC_Tax_Code
    [9] => CC_Shipping_Tax_Code
    [10] => CC_Default_Currency
    [11] => CC_Default_PriceType
    [12] => CC_Payment_DueType
    [13] => CC_ MethodInvoice
    [14] => CC_InvoiceTemplate
    [15] => CC_PrintPackingSlip
    [16] => CC_PackingSlip_Template
    [17] => CC_Card_Status
    [18] => CC_Fax
    [19] => CC_URL
    [20] => CC_ReviewedModifiedBy
)
Query PairsArray
(
    [CC_StoreID] => 89
    [EC_CC_Card_ID] => 54f2d1c6d6920
    [CC_Card_Type] => C
    [CC_Type] => I
    [CC_Company_Name] => Mr. Carl GettingFedUp
    [CC_Company_Trading_Name] => Individual
    [CC_ABN_Number] => Not Set
    [CC_Tax_Code] => GST
    [CC_Shipping_Tax_Code] => GST
    [CC_Default_Currency] => AU
    [CC_Default_PriceType] => R
    [CC_Payment_DueType] => PrePay
    [CC_ MethodInvoice] => E
    [CC_InvoiceTemplate] => Default
    [CC_PrintPackingSlip] => N
    [CC_PackingSlip_Template] => Default
    [CC_Card_Status] => Pending
    [CC_Fax] => Not Set
    [CC_URL] => Not Set
    [CC_ReviewedModifiedBy] => 0
)
Param VariablesArray
(
)
```

Which appears to match one to one with the perameters for the Prepaired statement, and yet I keep getting the subject line error.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Carl.

Comment: `CC_ MethodInvoice` <- remove that space

Comment: Man I spent 4 hours on that.  Unbelievable.
Thanks So Much.  Amazing what a second set of eyes will see.
Carl